# AttributeError: 'UUID' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

For reference, I've been primarily using these 2 resources

[AttributeError: 'UUID' object has no attribute 'replace' when using backend-agnostic GUID type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429929/attributeerror-uuid-object-has-no-attribute-replace-when-using-backend-agno)
https://websauna.org/docs/narrative/modelling/models.html#uuid-primary-keys

which seem to show that the issue is resolved though I can't seem to get it to work on my end.

My error is the same as in the SO post above but for thoroughness here it is:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/uuid.py", line 137, in __init__
    hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
AttributeError: 'UUID' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

My model is as follows:

```
import sqlalchemy
from .base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

class ModelItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),
            server_default=sqlalchemy.text("uuid_generate_v4()"), 
            primary_key=True, 
            nullable=False)
```

Are there other known work arounds?

Comment: Try to convert the hex variable into a string and then perform the replace task.

Comment: How would I go about that? It's done within the library so would I go into the module and switch up code there? That seems dangerous

Comment: How are you triggering this error?  I can't reproduce it from your code using sqlalchemy 1.3.10, psycopg2 2.8.4, python 3.8.

Answer (score -1):

hex = str(hex).replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')

Comment: What level of concern should I have for this causing errors in the future? It looks fine to do at first glance but not sure about what consequences it'll actually have

Comment: I feel it won't have any bad consequences as we are just typecasting the variable and storing it to a new instance of that same variable. We are not modifying the actual function or anything here.

To be more safe, store output is a new variable like:
new_hex = str(hex).replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')